# How to have multiple variants of an application on the same device?

Tags: android

I have to maintain relatively large android application. When I make changes and install it on the device, it installs over the previous version, making it unavailable. Meanwhile, I want both versions (changed and unchanged) installed, to compare theirs behavour. So for changed version cloned the code base and changed package attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml. But as a side effect, this causes errors when processing layout xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:cyberdyne="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cyberdyne.mobile"
          android:background="@drawable/back_grad">
     <TableRow android:paddingBottom="15dp">
          <com.cyberdyne.mobile.EmptyByDefaultSpinner

          ^ error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'defaultLabel' in package com.cyberdyne.mobile'

              android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              cyberdyne:defaultLabel="@string/labelRDCAccount"
              style="@style/DefaultAppearancePlus"/>
     </TableRow>
```

I read that the package in `xmlns:cyberdyne="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cyberdyne.mobile"` should be the same as in AndroidManifest.xml, but I do not want to change all the layout descriptions (there are many).

Is there a quick way to install more than one variants of an application on the same device, without massive changes in the codebase?

Comment: I think you cant have 2 application with same package name..So try by changing package name for your second version

Comment: Sorry, they assumed you'd always want to overwrite.  But if you use an IDE and do a global search and replace it should be easy to change all the names.  Or write a quick script, its just a walk through your res and src trees and a single regex.

Comment: Or, make another project copy with a different package name, use file-diff for comparing source changes.